# Proof that (A ∪ B)∘C = A∘C ∪ B∘C where A, B and C are languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

How can I prove this identity of languages?

My aproach is the following:

Let A, B and C to be languages, and let x to be an arbitrary string.

(A ∪ B) ⇒ x ∈ A ∨ x ∈ B

How do you proceed?

Comment: Use the definition of concatenation of languages and see if you find the same results for both sides of the equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep going. You've written what it means for $x$ to be in $A\cup B$. Now write out what it means for a string $y$ to be in $(A\cup B)\circ C$.  Do the same kind of thing on the right-hand side and relate the two statements you get.